# Is it possible to return HTTP code 200, but give a "better" url without using 3xx?

Tags: http, http-headers

Consider StackOverflow, where each question has a unique ID, but URLs are often overridden to include a stub in the URL. For readability and other reasons the stub helps users know they are at the right place.

I have a site that returns 200 when calling a URL like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057406/
```

But want the URL to update to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057406/is-it-possible-to-return-http-code-200-but-give-a-better-url-without-using-3x
```

The first call is technically valid and the code can retrieve the object and render it perfectly fine, but I'd like to update the URL to use the stubified one.

I'd prefer to do this without a redirect as just getting the ID causes a database call to get the object. Which would mean with a redirect the process would be:

1. Call `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057406/`
2. Retrieve item `25257999` from the database to get the name to make the stub
3. Redirect to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057406/is-it-possible-to-return-http-code-200-but-give-a-better-url-without-using-3x`
4. New HTTP Call, so retrieve item `25257999` from the database to render the final page.

If possible I'd like to not use Javascript either.

So, is it possible to return `Location` as part of a HTTP header with a status code of `200` and the actual page, or am I stuck using `3xx` calls or Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *just* doing HTTP, you can either choose to redirect, or not choose to redirect... You can also (with Content-Location) tell the client that the canonical address is actually somewhere else... but no browser will respond to that.

To avoid the database-call, you could of course just cache the result.

If you are in a browser however, you can dynamically update the current address without forcing a refresh, with `window.history.pushState`.

For more information about that call, see this other SO answer:

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)